# What's a good organization for Java code that works with an external API that is changing each version?

Tags: java

Specifically, there is a JSON RPC API that I work with. The specification might change between the API's versions, but I can always tell what version it is when I connect. I have about 30 wrappers methods that make use of the available JSON RPC methods.

Do you insert switch statements wherever you see changes in a way something should be called? Or write completely new methods to make it easier to manage, even if most of the API's functions didn't change and your code doesn't have to change?

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention I want my code to work with **multiple versions** of this API, ie. I can't just update my code to work with version 2.0 because I may want to use it on a different server that provides this service whose version is 1.8.

Comment: Can you put this mess behind a fixed interface or does its functionality also change?

Comment: This service doesn't have an interface that I can use in my code. There is a published list of JSON RPC methods that their service supports listed on a web page. Its functionality stays more or less the same. I am looking for a way to organize things so that they remain legible and maintainable.

Comment: You can write an interface that promises the functionality then write several implementations of it for each version of the server. At runtime you determine which implementation to use. Like @dicarlo2 suggests.

Comment: Hi can you share how this JSON-RPC API is versioned, I need to do something similar cause changing the data types in some of my request and response objects is causing a breaking change for the clients of my RPC API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would hide the external API behind your own internal interfaces, and then have implementations that deal with the external API's specific versions.

In other words, add another layer between you and the external API.

Comment: I am not sure if the "interface" of this service could change. I am not using a Java interface in my code, nor is one available for this service. There is a web-page with a list of JSON RPC methods that are available. I already have another layer - my own methods written in Java that invoke the provided RPC methods, but I am just getting around to dealing with the possibility of version change. I was looking more of a design pattern or actual code to suggest how to lay things out.

Comment: See [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for a more in-depth look at what I am suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for inheritance.

You can have a base class or interface and subclasses for each version.  You can even subclass the subclasses if it helps, for instance if there is a point release that only changes one method.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your code by using same idea of Data access object. What data access object is that it is a individual class that has methods to query database and retrieve data from it. For example if you have a class called Person and person class needs to access database to attain data such as phone number, firstname, lastname and etc. It can use this DAO (Short for Data access object) to get these values. The advantage of it is, let's say your boss asked you to change your database from MySQL to MongoDB. Then you do not have to change any single code from Person class and just modify DAO class to work with MongoDB instead of MySQL. My suggestion is that create a class that is built for that external API that you are using and make all your classes in your application to use this class to interact with the external API. Whenever API updates, you only need to modify (fix) this class and never have to touch any other classes. I hope you have understood what I mean =)